# Dynamic Link not found with Flutter Firebase Auth Passwordless SignIn (SignInWithEmailAndLink) in Android

Tags: dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use the new passwordless sign-in method implemented in the Flutter firebase_auth package.
I already followed the steps in order to receive the verification email, but after pressing on the link in the email, instead of being redirected to the app a web page saying "Dynamic Link not found" opens.

I'm on the latest Flutter stable channel 1.2.1, and I'm using the latest version of the firebase_auth package up to now 0.8.4+5. I'm also using the latest version of the firebase_dynamic_links package 0.2.1.

I tried with a manually created dynamic link and if I paste it in the browser it properly opens my app. It seems that the firebase_auth API for the passwordless sign-in generate a bad link.
I already tried different combinations of parameters and URLs, without success.

Here's how I call the firebase_auth API:

```
_auth.sendSignInWithEmailLink(
      email: email,
      url: 'https://mydomain.app/',
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      iOSBundleID: 'app.mypackage',
      androidPackageName: 'app.mypackage',
      androidInstallIfNotAvailable: false,
      androidMinimumVersion: '16',
    );
```

I also tried to pass a programmatically generated dynamic link:

```
final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      domain: 'myapp.page.link',
      link: Uri.parse('https://mydomain.app/'),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        fallbackUrl: Uri.parse('https://mydomain.app/'),
        packageName: 'app.mypackage',
        minimumVersion: 16,
      ),
    );

final ShortDynamicLink link = await parameters.buildShortLink();

_auth.sendSignInWithEmailLink(
      email: email,
      url: link.shortUrl.toString(),
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      iOSBundleID: 'app.mypackage',
      androidPackageName: 'app.mypackage',
      androidInstallIfNotAvailable: false,
      androidMinimumVersion: '16',
    );
```

Also, if I try to open the URL generated by `link.shortUrl.toString()`manually in the phone browser, my app opens.

I expect that the verification link in the email opens my app but for now it opens that page saying that the dynamic link doesn't work.

Comment: did you end up solving it? do you have a working example maybe? I can't seem to resolve it. it opens a new instance of the app....

Comment: same for me, it opens up a new instance of the app. Also `getInitialLink()` and `onLink()` returns null. If I paste a manually created link, it opens up with correct deeplink.

Comment: It is bad to know that the problem is still there. I had given up on the idea of using it and never looked at it again.